# ReactNative: name of the app on the top

Tags: react-native

I am new to app programming and I started with React Native. I want to put the name of my app on the top [(image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6AVg.png) and change the background color as well. How to put a static text on the top and what is that area called? Is it called `StatusBar`? If yes, how to put static text in the status bar?

Comment: Please post with code

Answer (score 0):

It's called `StatusBar` ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html)) and here is an example:

```
 <View>
   <StatusBar
     backgroundColor="blue"
     barStyle="light-content"
   />
   <Navigator
     initialRoute={{statusBarHidden: true}}
     renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
       <View>
         <StatusBar hidden={route.statusBarHidden} />
         ...
       </View>
     }
   />
 </View>
```

Please consider that the `backgroundColor` it's **ANDROID** specific props!

Also you can use UI Kits such as [Native Base](http://nativebase.io/) **OR** if you use `navigation` libraries, they have header option in most cases!

Take a look at [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for an example!